# Microservices with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, microservices, backend

I would like to move from MVC to microservices with next js, but at the same time I have no idea how to get started and what to learn.
I would really appreciate it if someone could provide me with a brief roadmap on the things I should learn and explain how the file structure would look like.
I should also mention that I'm a frontend dev who's trying to get into the backend and I have some basic knowledge of how the backend works